# Felder Kazhdan classical master equation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

Has there been any follow up by anyone to
Giovanni Felder, David Kazhdan, The classical master equation (arXiv:1212.1631)?
Other than on nlab, I haven't found any citations.

Comment: Well, it has only been a few months...